# Traduction de l'idiome anglais « in the chips »

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

Quelle est l'expression française correspondant à « *to be in the chips* » dans
« *I'm in the chips this month. Let's go squander it.* » ?

Answer (score 3):

"Etre plein aux as". "En avoir plein les pognes".

Je traduirais la phrase complète par quelque chose comme : "Je suis plein aux as, ce mois-ci ; on va faire la nouba / on va s'en payer (une tranche)".

Remarques :

- c'est une expression plus US que UK ;
- ma traduction respecte le ton très familier. Mais tout Parisien vous comprendra.

Comment: Esprit de l'escalier : "to be in one's chips"  = "to kick the bucket", cela n'a rien à voir,  traduit selon le même registre argotique : "casser sa pipe".

Comment: Tu peux éditer tes propres réponses en utilisant le bouton idoine situé juste en-dessous.

Comment: D'accord, merci, je suis nouveau et loin de maîtriser les manipulations.