# Ressources pour décortiquer et éplucher des tournures idiomatiques

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques, ressources

Je me hasarde à dépister une ressource ou un dictionnaire français, soit sur Internet soit téléchargeable, qui discourt de et expose le dessein, la genèse, la structure, voire l'intuition, des tournures idiomatiques, outre leurs définitions et sens. En existe-t-il ? J'ai pris conscience que la mémorisation des définitions ne m'aide guère; en saisissant leur contexte, je les remémore plus souvent. Toutefois, je ne m'enquiers pas de l'étymologie.

Par exemple, à partir de [Traduction de l'idiome anglais « in the chips »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/traduction-de-lidiome-anglais-in-the-chips):

**En avoir plein les [pognes](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/pogne/61971?q=pognes#61272) =** Avoir plein [les mains ou Brioche en couronne (Lequel? Ce mot détient 2 acceptions ?)] de qqch.
Comment et pourquoi est-ce que ça signifie « être plein aux as (une monnaie romane antique) »? Cet idiome je pige.

**On va s'en payer (une tranche) =** On va se payer un morceau de qqch = On va être payé un morceau de qqch.
Comment et pourquoi est-ce que ça signifie « s'amuser beaucoup » ? Quand bien même on se payerait un tas de qqch qui vaut la peine et de grande valeur, la luxure n'engendre pas le bonheur et fait qu'on s'amuse ?

Comment: Pourquoi vouloir à tout prix trouver un sens littéral à [toutes](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/7951/1129) [ces](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/7878/1129) [expressions](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/7990/1129)?

Comment: Petite remarque sans rapport avec la question. Plutôt que de vouloir acquérir une connaissance encyclopédique des tournures idiomatiques, tu ferais mieux d'approfondir comment on utilise celles dont tu connais déjà le sens.  D'une part tu en uses tellement que tu en abuses ce qui donne une désagréable impression de vouloir étaler ton savoir, d'autre part tu es capable d'en employer deux dans la même phrase, une formelle et au charme désuet et l'autre plutôt moderne et familière dans une conjonction à l'effet improbable et donnant l'impression que tu cherches à étaler un savoir non maîtrisé.

Comment: Dans ton cas je pense qu'il ne te faut pas utiliser une seule ressource mais croiser les ressources en modifiant tes méthodes d'investigation. Taper pogne+sens dans google te renverra à plusieurs définitions, par exemple [1](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pogne), [2](http://www.languefrancaise.net/bob/detail.php?id=2043), et tu vois tout de suite que pogne dans le sens culinaire a un emploi très restreint. Et il faut utiliser sons bon sens : de façon universelle on a plus de chances d'avoir du pognon (argot pour argent) dans ses mains que caché dans des brioches du sud de la France.

Comment: Pour ce qui est de tranche il est facile de trouver ([1](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/s-en-payer-une-bonne-tranche.php) ou [2](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tranche)) que ce mot a aussi un sens abstrait et que « se payer »  n'implique pas forcément un échange d'argent ([1](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/payer), [2](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/payer)).

Comment: Comme le remarque @Unfrancophone, tu ferais en effet mieux d'utiliser des tournures plus simples dans tes questions. C'est parfois vraiment alambiqué, un véritable fouillis de synonymes, à tel point que j'imagine que beaucoup de natifs comme moi ont du mal à comprendre tes questions. Et je ne parle même pas des débutants, même ceux d'un niveau moyen, qui probablement n'y comprendront rien, et ne pourront pas en tirer grand chose. Ce qui est dommage pour un site de partage de connaissances comme FL&U.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon: Je vous remercie de vos commentaires. Je répond à votre 1e question ici. Simplement parce que sans le sens littéral, il m'apparaît que je les oublie à fond. Avec lui, je pourrai les débrouiller, quand bien même je les oublierais. Est-ce sensé ? SVP, prière de me faire savoir d'autres suggestion et conseils.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon: pour un non natif (ce qui, je suppose, est le cas de LePressentiment) il est difficile d'apprécier le niveau de langue et la difficulté d'une tournure, surtout si on n'a qu'une pratique livresque de la langue.

Comment: @Laure : j'ai du mal à imaginer quelqu'un utilisant couramment *hasarder*, *dessein*, *genèse*, *enquérir*, et qui n'aurait utilisé le français qu'à l'écrit, sans jamais être confronté au langage familier des medias ou d'une conversation orale. Mais je me trompe peut-être...

Comment: @Unfrancophone: D'ailleurs, vous avez écrit :  *D'une part tu en uses tellement que tu en abuses ce qui donne une désagréable impression de vouloir étaler ton savoir*. SVP, veuillez me faire savoir des erreurs auxquelles vous faites allusion car je veux m'améliorer. Au demeurant, la raison pourrait être le fait que je ne suis pas un locuteur natif, et non pas un étalage.

Comment: @Unfrancophone: Merci de votre commentaire. Je vous riposte à part. Toutefois, je ne vise pas à "acquérir une connaissance encyclopédique." Comme j'ai exprimé dans l'OP, sans le pouvoir de les raisonner, je les oublierais sur-le-champ, quand bien même je les mémorises. SVP, veuillez me faire savoir d'autres suggestion et conseils.

Comment: *SVP, veuillez me faire savoir des erreurs auxquelles vous faites allusion car je veux m'améliorer.* Il n'y a pas d'erreurs (ou vraiment très très peu). Ton niveau de français est vraiment bon à l'écrit, mais tu utilises souvent des expressions d'un niveau très soutenu, mélangées parfois à du langage familier, et ces sauts dans les registres de langue rend la compréhension difficile.

Comment: @Unfrancophone: Absolument, je voudrais 'approfondir comment on utilise celles dont tu connais déjà le sens.` En même temps, je tombe sur les nouvelles tournures, qui explique pourquoi j'ai affiché cette question. À propos, pourriez-vous m'apprendre le sens de `au charme désuet` dans votre commentaire ?  Charme (nom masculin) connote l'air positif, et désuet celui de négatif ?

Comment: @AlexisPigeon: Je vous reste reconnaissant. Je dois toujours m'améliorer, ainsi veuillez me faire savoir d'une erreur quelconque, même celles très petites. Je vais y réfléchir. A propos de votre 1e question, mon mode de remémorer et saisir les idiomes, est-il efficace et sensé ? Sinon, veuillez me le faire savoir. Comme Laure l'a dit, je le trouve difficile.

Comment: @Laure: Je vous remercie de vos commentaires et vous prie de les convertir en une réponse, si vous n'avez pas d'objection, pour laquelle je plussoyerai.

Comment: @LePressentiment:  Mes commentaires ne relèvent pas d'une réponse. Faire des points n'est pas le but premier. Par ailleurs je te signale que je t'ai laissé des messages sur sur le chat pour essayer de te donner quelques pistes pour rendre ton français plus idiomatiques.

Comment: @cl-r: Je pense que c'était du *luxe* dont il était question.

Comment: @LePressentiment J'ai apporté une correction à votre question en utilisant *la luxure*, car j'y ai lu deux ***u***, correction typographique qui aurait pu être faite, comme le suggère Stéphane, en *le luxe* rattaché au masculin ***le***. Quelle était votre première idée : notion de dépense excessive ou d’excès sensuel ?

Comment: Dans « être pleins aux as », as ne fait pas référence à la monnaie romaine mais à l'as du jeu de carte. [Voir](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8000/pourquoi-as-peut-il-a-la-fois-signifier-sans-valeur-et-riche)

Comment: @cl-r: Merci! Les deux, en fait. J'imaginais que `payer` désigne du blé et ainsi la luxure.

Comment: @Laure: Merci. Voilà une des destinations de mon OP.

Answer (score 3):

Dans mes élucubrations, il n’est pas rare que je tombe sur [expressio.fr](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/s-en-payer-une-bonne-tranche.php) qui, malgré un manque récurrent de références<sup>1</sup>, t’aidera à comprendre nombre d’expressions.

---

1. Manque de référence qui me fait parfois douter de la validité des origines qu’ils proposent.

Comment: Ça doit être la première fois que je vois [_élucubration_](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9lucubration) utilisé dans le premier sens du TLFi chez un contemporain.

Comment: Expressio.fr que j'ai indiqué, entre autres, dans les références données à LePresentiment en commentaires. J'y retrouve souvent les mêmes explications  que dans le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sld A.Rey) qui figure explicitement dans les [sources](http://www.expressio.fr/sources.php) des auteurs du site.

Comment: Le lien correspond bien à la demande de recherche sur internet. Il donnera à LePressentiment une tonalité, une musicalité d'usage, la clef de compréhension des idiomes et souvent leur étymologie. @Laure Pourquoi ne pas mettre vos commentaires en réponse afin que nous puissions cliquer sur la flèche du haut ?

Comment: @cl-r: Je pense avoir déjà clairement donné mon avis sur ce point dans mon commentaire sous la question du PO.