# Pourquoi « As » peut-il à la fois signifier « sans valeur » et « riche » ?

Tags: sens, étymologie, expressions-idiomatiques

Cette question m'a été soufflée par une remarque figurant dans cette [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7994/ressources-pour-decortiquer-et-eplucher-des-tournures-idiomatiques)

> Comment et pourquoi est-ce « être plein aux as » signifie être riche ?

L'expression *ça ne vaut pas un as* veut dire : « ça n'a aucune valeur », alors que *être plein aux as* veut dire « être riche ».
Comment en est-on arrivé à employer un même mot dans des sens apparemment opposés ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Mot supposé d'origine étrusque <sup>1</sup> **as** désignait chez les romains une unité de mesure (poids et monnaie) et la pièce de plus petite valeur dans le système monétaire romain à l'âge classique.
Cette valeur latine du mot en français est toujours restée cantonnée au contexte romain antique et n'est pas passé dans l'usage courant.

C'est en entrant dans le domaine du jeu que le mot en est venu à désigner de l'argent en français. 
Le mot a été repris dans le domaine du jeu pour désigner au 12ème siècle la face d'un dé marqué d'**un seul** point et plus tard (1546) on le trouve chez [Rabelais](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Rabelais) pour désigner, dans chaque couleur, la carte marquée d'**un seul** point et, au 18ème siècle, pour désigner dans le jeu de dominos la pièce marquée d'**un seul** point. On peut penser **un seul point**, comme l'unité de base que représentait l'as romain.<sup>2</sup>

La valeur de la face de dé marqué d'un point, la plus faible,  a servi à forger des expressions où **as**  signifie « sans valeur » : *de deux as*, *ne valoir un as*, *bouffer à l’as* (jeûner)<sup>1</sup> et <sup>3</sup>.

Je n'ai pas trouvé de références pour dire comment dans le jeu de cartes l'**as** (la carte marquée d'**un seul point**) en est venu à désigner la carte qui a **le plus de valeur**. Mais c'est de ce sens là que **as** a pris le sens d'argent, et on le trouve avec ce sens dans : *être à l'as* (1881), *être aux as* (1916) et *être plein aux as* (1909), seule la dernière de ces expressions est encore employée de nos jours. [Certaines références](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/plein-aux-as.php) relient *plein aux as* au [full](http://www.poker-regle-strategie.com/regles/full.php) au poker.
Le sens de la plus forte carte au jeu a aussi conduit à l'utilisation du mot dans le domaine du sport où **as** peut désigner celui qui arrive en tête.

Il existe de très nombreuses expressions utilisant le mot **as** mais où la référence principale n'est pas le mot **as** mais [l'enseigne](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enseigne_%28carte_%C3%A0_jouer%29) portée sur la carte, comme [*être fait comme l'as de pique*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AAtre_habill%C3%A9_%C3%A0_l%E2%80%99as_de_pique), l'as de pique désignant, par analogie de forme, le croupion d'une volaille<sup>1</sup>, [un as de carreau](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/as_de_carreau) désignait  (1858, jusqu'en 1917)  un sac de soldat, aussi par analogie de forme.<sup>1</sup>
Le [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/as) donne de très nombreuses autres expressions contenant le mot **as**.

<sup>1</sup> : *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sld A. Rey)
<sup>2</sup> : Wikipedia [mentionne](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_%28carte_%C3%A0_jouer%29) que l'emploie pour le jeu de cartes renverrait à l'unité de monnaie romaine qui était sans doute employée pour parier, mais je n'ai trouvé aucune autre référence au fait que les romains utilisaient l'as pour parier, pas non plus dans l'article de Wikipédia consacré à l'[as, monnaie romaine](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_%28monnaie%29). Bien sûr on peut penser que de toute façon n'importe quelle monnaie peut être utilisée dans des paris...
<sup>3</sup> http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/passer_%C3%A0_l%E2%80%99as

Comment: Pour le passage de la carte la plus faible à celle avec la plus forte valeur, c'est peut-être lié à l'avènement de jeux l'utilisant comme carte la plus forte (ex: poker), bien que dans d'autre elle reste la plus faible (tarot).

Answer (score 1):

*As* n'as pas deux signifisations opposées, pas plus que *kopek* ou *rond*.
Quand on en a même pas un c'est qu'on est pauvre et quand on en a beaucoup c'est qu'on est riche.

Comment: Non, les deux emplois ne sont pas opposés, le mot a désigné des choses différentes à des époques différentes.  Quand on dit qu'on est plein aux as la métaphore vient du jeu de carte et ça veut dire qu'on a les cartes gagnantes (et donc qu'on va s'enrichir). Il n'a pas le sens de la pièce de plus petite valeur (le mot n'est pas employé dans ce sens là de nos jours) ou la face du dé qui a le moins de valeur.

Comment: En effet les emplois sont identiques car les deux indiquent une valeur. Dans l'un elle est faible dans l'autre elle est forte.

Answer (score 1):

C'est le même sens, as signifie une valeur élevée, mais il y a une négation dans l'un des deux exemples.

"Ca ne vaut pas un as" --> ça n'a pas de valeur

"être plein aux as" --> avoir beaucoup de valeurs (financières)