# « (Pas) pour cinq cennes » (pas du tout) : négation de la présence de l'infime quantité, comparaison avec le centime ?

Tags: prépositions, prononciation, orthographe, québec, locutions

Au Québec, on a la locution adverbiale [*(pas) pour cinq cennes*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pas_pour_cinq_cennes), voire *(pas) pour une [cent](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cent)*, dans le sens de *pas du tout* ; je le vois comme le constat de l'absence d'une quantité même infime (comme le [*iota*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/iota)) : même pas pour cinq cennes, donc pas du tout. Le mot [*cent*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3666) ([/sɛnt/](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cent#Prononciation), essentiellement comme en [anglais](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cent#Pronunciation)) pour l'unité monétaire au Canada par exemple (le centième de dollar canadien) est [masculin](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cent#Nom_commun_2) mais il fait l'objet au Québec d'un emploi au féminin avec la graphie [*cenne*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cenne) et sa prononciation /sɛn/ :

> Pas maline pour une cent (J.-J. Richard, Centre-Ville, Montréal, 1973,
>   p. 59, ds. TLFi).
>  [...] Pas nostalgique pour cinq cennes. (Le
>   Devoir, 23 octobre 2006, ds. Wiktionnaire)

---

1. La graphie détermine-t-elle absolument la prononciation,
   prononce-t-on *pour une cent* /sɛnt/ ou /sɛn/ ; *pour une cent*
   est-elle aussi usuelle ou lexicalisée que *pour cinq cennes* et y
   a-t-il une différence dans l'emploi ou le sens de l'une ou l'autre ?
2. Ailleurs est-ce qu'on a de telles locutions adverbiales qui sont usuelles aujourd'hui
   avec l'infime quantité monétaire ([*centime*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/centime), ce serait 1, 10,
   ou 25 qui serait encore usuel, ou c'est [*sou*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sou), *balle, jeton*...) ou autrement,
   et surtout avec quelle préposition introduit-on le tout et comment
   formule-t-on : l'adjectif est-il intercalé entre la négation et la
   locution comme dans les deux exemples ?

Comment: À chaud, j'ai pensé à «ça ne vaut pas un kopeck», le kopeck étant bien une unité monétaire de valeur minimale, mais d'origine russe, et à ma connaissance non utilisée dans quelque pays francophone que ce soit.

Comment: @Feelew C'est sans doute _sou_ qui est le commun dénominateur avec _un_ je me dis. Je suis vaguement familier avec le mot _kopeck_ dont vous parlez, je l'aurais déjà entendu à qq. part. Je m'attends à ce qu'ailleurs ds. la francophonie on n'intercale pas entre la négation et le reste mais que négation et la locution précèdent plutôt l'adjectif. À vrai dire je sais pas. Merci !

Comment: À ma connaissance en France on dit "pas maline pour un sou", "pas maline pour deux sous", "pas maline pour trois sous".

Comment: Un exemple d’un lointain passé: *Ça ne vaut pas un as!* (https://french.stackexchange.com/q/8000)

Answer (score 2):

Je réponds d'une perspective française.

Ici le mot *cenne* est complètement inconnu. Un centième de franc se disait *centime* (et se dit encore en Suisse). Un centième d'euro se dit encore le plus souvent *centime* mais on dit aussi *cent*, prononcé à l'anglaise [sɛnt].

Je suppose que *cenne* est apparu parce que la succession de consonnes [nt] passe mal en français, et on ne peut pas prononcer le mot *cent* comme il s'écrit parce qu'on confondrait avec l'homonyme *cent* [sɑ̃] qui veut dire 100.

Pour dire que quelque chose ne vaut rien, on peut dire que ça ne vaut pas un sou. Il y a d'autres variantes : *pas un rond* (un ancien synonyme de *sou*), *pas un kopeck* (je suppose parce que c'est la plus petite unité, et en plus comme c'est une monnaie étrangère elle ne vaut rien ici), ou plus simplement (mais plus rarement) *pas un centime*. En langage familier, *pas un rond* est l'expression la plus courante, surtout pour dire que l'on n'a pas d'argent (« je suis fauché, j'ai pas un rond »). Le sou étant une ancienne unité monétaire qui valait cinq centimes, l'expression québecoise avec « 5 cennes » est probablement une traduction dans la nouvelle unité monétaire. Cependant l'expression correspondant à « pas [adjectif] pour cinq cennes » (Québec) est « pas [adjectif] pour deux sous » (France) (ce qui ferait donc dix cennes).

Comment: Merci ! Ouais le _rond_, ça m'avait échappé ça... J'aimais vraiment _balle_ !

Answer (score 1):

À ma connaissance, «pas cinq cennes» vient de l'expression populaire québécoise, «Ça vaut pas cinq cennes» qui veut dire que l'objet, le produit, le service dont il est question ne vaut qu'on pas qu'on l'achète pour 5 cents. Notez que le q de cinq ne se prononce pas dans cette expression populaire.

1. La graphie détermine la prononciation de cenne, mais pas de cinq.
2. La cenne fait référence au cent de la monnaie canadienne.